# PHP get_headers fails on https://www.ticketmaster.com

Tags: php, curl, https

I have code which validates whether a URL is OK, starting with get_headers() with a variety of user agents and then trying CURL. If I try:

```
get_headers('https://www.ticketmaster.com/');
```

This hangs for a long time and then returns false.

The equivalent CURL call behaves similarly.

If I open a Mac terminal window and try:

```
wget('https://www.ticketmaster.com');
```

It says it's connected to www.ticketmaster.com, but hangs while awaiting the response and eventually times out.

The URL works fine in a browser (obviously), and it's also considered OK by SSL Checker.

Any ideas for what Ticketmaster are doing weirdly, and how to check for it?

Comment: TicketMaster likely has **very** aggressive anti-bot measures due to scalpers trying to buy up all the tickets to resell at 10x the cost. You will probably not be able to scrape it.

Comment: You will most likely need to emulate a browser request. So all the HTTP headers a browser usually sends.

Comment: Thanks both - I expect you're both correct. I had already emulated USER_AGENT, but it looks as if I'm going to half to look through all the headers that Chrome sends and systematically emulate all of them. It seems a lot of work since all I'm trying to do is to check whether the Ticketmaster URL is valid (we're an aggregator, not a ticket resale scammer), but I guess that will be what it takes.